# Question on DB relationships

Tags: database-design

I have an employees table, and I want to track their Operating System preferences.
They can have more than one OS preference:

```
Employee
 - ID
 - Name 
 - OS_Prefs_ID

OSTypes
 - ID
 - OperatingSystemName
 - Version

OS_Prefs
 - ID
 - OSTypes_ID
```

Is the relationship between Employee and OS_Prefs "one to many" or "many to many"?

I am guessing that Employees (1) to OS_Prefs (many) and for OSTypes and OS_Prefs, it seems that it is OS_Prefs (many) to OSTypes (1).  Right?

Comment: yup you are correct. one employee has many os preferences. and many ostypes have many preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am guessing that Employees (1) to OS_Prefs (many) and for OSTypes and OS_Prefs, it seems that it is OS_Prefs (many) to OSTypes (1). Right?

That is the way it should be, making the relationship from Employee to OSType many-to-many

But for that you need to change your schema a little:

Employee

- ID
- Name

OSTypes

- ID
- OperatingSystemName
- Version

OS_Prefs

- employee_ID
- OSTypes_ID

Comment: and for OS_Prefs, it doesn't need a primary key because that would not provide any extra information, right?

Comment: I'd make employee_id + ostype_id the primary key. m:n mapping tables are one of the few exceptions where I accept a combined primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Many-to-Many

Very simply put an Employee can have many operatingsystems and an operating system can have many employees.

That's why you need to use a third table which contains both ID's

Answer (score 1):

> Is the relationship between Employee
>   and OS_Prefs "one to many" or "many to
>   many"?
>
> I am guessing that Employees (1) to
>   OS_Prefs (many) and for OSTypes and
>   OS_Prefs, it seems that it is OS_Prefs
>   (many) to OSTypes (1). Right?

Yes, correct.

BTW, the relationship you are really trying to model is Employees <-> OSTypes. This is a many-to-many relationship. As this cannot be (nicely) done with two tables, you use a third table (OS_Prefs), to decompose the many-to-many into one one-to-many and one many-to-one. This is a common technique, called a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_Table) .

Answer (score 0):

One to one, as I see it.

Make it so:

```
Employee
 - ID
 - Name 

OSTypes
 - ID
 - OperatingSystemName
 - Version

OS_Prefs
 - EmployeeID
 - OSTypes_ID
```

Comment: If an employee can have multiple preferences it can never be one-to-one. Unless you completely neglect all normilasation